# Series where they find a key and chest that leads to ancient rome

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

Sorry for the vagueness but I remember watching a series of sorts in class in school about 10-15 years ago. It involved some sort of quest to find a chest and/or key that when eventually unlocked opened a pathway to ancient Rome. It led into some sort of building where all the romans were walking around and I think an episode ended on one of them going into the portal. Any ideas?

Think it was an English series.

Comment: Could you define 'a long time ago'? Maybe even edit that information into your question. Anything else you remember (length of an episode etc.)?

Comment: 10-15 years ago, but the show seemed older than that. Length of an episode was maybe an hour?

Comment: Do you remember the nationality of the show?

Comment: Could you please please correct the mistyping in  "ancient" in the title?

Comment: I'd imagine it was English.

Answer (score 4):

Is it possibly the "[Box of Delights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Box_of_Delights)"?  It was a British children's series based loosely on the book of the same name.  It was rebroadcast in the USA in the 1980's as part of the "Wonderworks" series on PBS.  The story concerned a magical box with vast powers that was being pursued by sinister-but-debonair werewolves.  There were a number of separate adventures relating to the box, but one included the main character entering the box and ending up in Roman times.

The series had a wonderfully spooky atmosphere and has always been one of my favorites. It doesn't seem to be currently available for purchase, but you can find the entire thing on You Tube.

Answer (score 2):

Think you are thinking of ["The Legend of the Lost Keys"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_the_Lost_Keys), which was part of the Look and Read series. We used to watch it in primary school too.

EDIT: If my memory serves correct, the city Heritron in the series was in a parallel universe where Rome never fell - which would explain why the OP thought it was Rome. The entire series was styled in a "Roman" manner: with togas, and a Janus organisation, and a roman numeral riddle in the first episode (I think).

Comment: Can you explain how it matches?

Comment: That was about a box that led to a world called Heritron - AFAIK it had nothing to do with Rome